# Switch or If Else for Set Image Resource in Android

Tags: java, android

I have an imagebutton. Default icon of imagebutton is play_icon.
When I pressed that button I want it to be pause_icon and all goes like that.

I wrote this, but didn't make it. Any idea?

```
img1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        switch(view.getId()){
            case R.mipmap.play_icon:
                img1.setImageResource(R.mipmap.pause_icon);
            case R.mipmap.pause_icon:
                img1.setImageResource(R.mipmap.play_icon);
            break;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: You miss the `break` at the end of the first `case`

Comment: If there are more if condition then always go with switch.

Comment: this is not the main issue, R.mipmap.play_icon is not a View and it not represents a View ID!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`R.mipmap.play_icon` is not a valid  View ID, it represents the id for your icon and not for your `ImageButton` to fix it, change your method to this:

```
final boolean firstClick = false;
    img1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

               if(firstClick){
                    img1.setImageResource(R.mipmap.pause_icon);
                } else{

                    img1.setImageResource(R.mipmap.play_icon);
                 } 
            firstClick = !firstClick;
            }
        });
```

Comment: It worked! But I declared boolean in main class as normal not final.